# ¿Porque el modal al que paso un objeto en un ngFor para en un @input de Angular solo toma el primer dato que le paso y este replica a los demás?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

estoy teniendo problema , estoy abriendo un componente modal el cual estoy repitiendo desde un ngform, y le paso un objeto Empresa para que al abrir el modal me muestre los datos de este, pero este siempre me muestra los datos solamente del primero y no entiendo porque tengo ese comportamiento.

acá un poco de código para entenderlo mejor,

Tengo el componente empresas el cual consta de

empresa typescript

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmpresaService } from 'src/app/services/empresa.service';
    import { Empresa } from 'src/app/models/empresa';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    
    
    
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'empresa.component.html',
    })
    export class EmpresaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
      p = 1;
      searchText = '';
      empresas: Empresa[] = [];
      loader: boolean;
      empSubscription: Subscription;
    
      constructor(private empresaService: EmpresaService) {
    
      }
    
    
    
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.getAllcompanies();
    
      }
    
      // Get tha users data from the user service
      getAllcompanies() {
        this.loader = true;
        this.empSubscription = this.empresaService.getCompanies().subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.empresas = data.empresas;
          // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
          this.empresas = this.empresas.filter(empresa => empresa.activo == 1);
        });
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.empSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    
    }
ý su template empresa.html

    <div class="animated fadeIn">
      <!-- row header -->
      <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <p class="h2 ml-4 mt-1">Filtrar Contenido</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
              <div class="active-cyan-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text border border-success bg-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control border border-success" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Empresa"
                    type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-end mt-1">
              <app-moda-emp-crear></app-moda-emp-crear>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- row header -->
    



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fa fa-building"></i> Listado de Empresas
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive-sm">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <!-- <th>NRC</th> -->
                <!-- <th>NIT</th> -->
                <th>Giro</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>                
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let empresa of empresas  |filter:searchText |paginate: {itemsPerPage:8, currentPage:p}; index as i">
                <td>{{empresa.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{empresa.direccion}}</td>
                <!-- <td>{{empresa.registroFiscal}}</td> -->
                <!-- <td>{{empresa.nit}}</td> -->
                <td>{{empresa.giro}}</td>
                <td>{{empresa.direccion}}</td>
                <td>{{empresa.telefono}}</td>

                <td *ngIf="empresa.activo == 1">
                  Activo
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="empresa.activo== 0">
                  Inactivo
                </td>

                <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <app-modal-emp-detail [id]="empresa.id" *ngIf="empresa.activo == 1"></app-modal-emp-detail>
                  <app-modal-edit-emp [id]="empresa.id" *ngIf="empresa.activo == 1"></app-modal-edit-emp>
                  <app-confirm-modal></app-confirm-modal>
                </td>                
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" (pageBoundsCorrection)="p = $event" previousLabel="Anterior"
              nextLabel="Siguiente">
            </pagination-controls>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fin table de Cuentas-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto se ve así
[image: imagen de muestra]

Ahora al dar clic al botón del el ojo o del lápiz abre un modal que debería mostrar la data correspondiente al row, para esto esto utilizando @output, pero el problema es que realmente solo muestra los datos repetidos del primer row.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y bien para este he creado un componente modal.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPatient">
    <i class="fa  fa-eye"></i>
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true"
    id="editPatient">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Informacion Empresa</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- inicio formulario -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

                    <!-- Empresa Nombre -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Empresa</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.nombre">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Empresa Nombre -->


                    <!-- Direccion -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Direccion</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.direccion">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Direccion -->


                    <!-- Registro Fiscal -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">RF</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled
                                [value]="empresa.registroFiscal">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Registro Fiscal -->

                    <!-- Telefono -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.telefono">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Telefono -->

                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- NEmail-->

                    <!-- NIT -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">NIT</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.nit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- NIT -->

                    <!-- Razon -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Razon Social</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled
                                [value]="empresa.razonSocial">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- NRazon-->

                    <!-- Razon -->
                    <div class="form-group row mx-1">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">Giro</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" disabled [value]="empresa.giro">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- NRazon-->

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>                        
                      </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <!-- fin formulario  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y su archivo ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { EmpresaService } from 'src/app/services/empresa.service';
import { Empresa } from 'src/app/models/empresa';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-emp-detail',
  templateUrl: './modal-emp-detail.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ModalEmpDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  empresa: Empresa;
  @Input() id: string;
  empSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private empresaService: EmpresaService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.empresa = new Empresa();
    this.getEmpresa();
  }

  getEmpresa(): void {
    this.empSubscription = this.empresaService.getOneCompany(this.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.empresa = data.empresa;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.empSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }    
}
```

y este es el servicio donde ambos obtienen la data

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Empresa } from '../models/empresa';
import { global } from './global';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmpresaService {

  MAIN_URL = global.url;
  userToken: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.readToken();
  }

  getCompanies() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', JSON.parse(this.userToken));
    return this.http.get(this.MAIN_URL + 'empresas', { headers });
  }


  getOneCompany(id: string) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', JSON.parse(this.userToken));
    return this.http.get(this.MAIN_URL + 'empresa/' + id, { headers });
  }


  editCompany(empresa: Empresa) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(empresa);
    const params = 'json=' + json;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .set('Authorization', JSON.parse(this.userToken));
    return this.http.put(this.MAIN_URL + 'empresa/actualizar', params, { headers });
  }

  /*
  Crear una  Empresa
  */

 createCompany(empresa: Empresa) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(empresa);
  const params = 'json=' + json;
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    .set('Authorization', JSON.parse(this.userToken));
  return this.http.post(this.MAIN_URL + 'empresa/crear', params, { headers });
}

  // createCompany(empresa: Empresa) {
  //   const datos = {
  //     nombre: empresa.nombre,
  //     direccion: empresa.direccion,
  //     registroFiscal: empresa.registroFiscal,
  //     telefono: empresa.telefono,
  //     tamanoEmpresa_id: empresa.tamanoEmpresa_id,
  //     nit: empresa.nit,
  //     logo: empresa.logo,
  //     razonSocial: empresa.razonSocial,
  //     giro: empresa.giro,
  //     email: empresa.email,
  //     activo: empresa.activo
  //   };
  //   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  //     .set('Authorization', JSON.parse(this.userToken));
  //   console.log('Servicio crear empresa corriendo');
  //   console.log('datos', JSON.stringify(datos));
  //   return this.http.post(this.MAIN_URL + 'empresa/crear', { json: datos }, { headers });
  // }


  /****************
  **Read the token
  *****************/
  readToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      this.userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    } else {
      this.userToken = '';
    }
    return this.userToken;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando un modal propio para cada empresa pero con el mismo id para todos

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" id="editPatient">
```

Lo que se debería hacer es crear un id único, para ello puedes aprovechar el id de la empresa y en el componente modal hacer algo así:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#editPatient-' + id">
<i class="fa  fa-eye"></i>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" id="editPatient-{{id}}">
```